# LaTeX "command" /incantation for R

Tags: r

I am using the tufte-handout class in LaTeX and I want to refer to [R](http://www.r-project.org) using the "correct" sans-serif font.  I am currently using

```
\newcommand{\R}{ {\bf \sffamily R } }
```

used as ...

```
... function in the \verb|spatstat| \R package ...
```

What LaTeX "command" / incantation would you use?

Comment: Rather than flagging to close just because it's easy to do, why not flag for moderator attention to migrate, even though it takes a *little* more effort??

Comment: This is surely a duplicate; anyway, the answer is `\newcommand{\R}{\textbf{\textsf{R}}}`. Never use the two letter commands `\bf`, `\sf` or `\it`, they are obsolete.

Comment: @egreg: I agree, I just thought the attitude of the folks @ SO a bit less than constructive

Comment: Related (but here it appears that the "R" is *not* desired in sans serif font): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73089/forcing-roman-font-in-latex Indeed in the R manual the "R" is just in the roman font (possibly bold in a bold context). So `\newcommand{\R}{\textup{R}}` might be better.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the link. Opinion seems mixed, the Springer books (including MASS4) use sans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ensure a sans serif upright bold font, just define

```
\newcommand{\R}{\textnormal{\sffamily\bfseries R}}}
```

If you want to avoid typing `\R{} is a nice program`, then

```
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\R}{\textnormal{\sffamily\bfseries R}}\xspace}
```

will allow

```
\R is a nice program
```