# How to set roman font to make references to R?

Tags: fonts, r, roman

I'm writing a thesis and I need to make references to R. I've read some other articles that cite "R" and they seem to use the roman font. I have no idea how to set this font :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucky for us, this question has already been answered here: 
[Forcing roman font in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73089/forcing-roman-font-in-latex?rq=1)

The idea is to use  `\textrm{R}`.

Many of those simpler questions already have an answer somewhere on this site.

Good luck with your thesis!

Comment: If there is a similar question with the same answer, why not mark this question as a duplicate of the other?

Comment: In addition, sometimes, could be used sans font for R logo: `\textsf{R}`.